# NGINX macOS Sierra brew vs sudo

Tags: nginx, mac-osx

I am encountering an issue with NGINX behaving differently with the following start commands:

```
brew services start nginx
```

vs

```
sudo nginx
```

When i start nginx with `sudo nginx`, everything seem to work normal.
But when I try to start nginx with `brew service start nginx`, it would start and work fine if I load pages I loaded before using `sudo nginx`, but anything new would not load. I would have to use `sudo nginx` to load that page first.

`brew services list` shows the nginx as started, but the status is in yellow

```
Name  Status  User    Plist
nginx started usera /Users/usera/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
php71 started usera /Users/usera/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php71.plist
```

Here's my `nginx.conf` file

```
user usera admin;
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;

    keepalive_timeout 65;

    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            root html;
            index index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root html;
        }
    }

    # Include Configuration
    #include conf.d/*.conf;

    # Include Enabled Sites
    include sites-enabled/*;

    include servers/*;
}
```

`default` service configuration file

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name default.localhost;

    location / {
        root html/default;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`nginx` needs to be executed as root to have access to all necessary resources. [It can be configured to be run as non-root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329261/running-nginx-as-non-root-user).

Alternatively, it can be run using `sudo` on the `brew services` command:

```
sudo brew services start nginx
```

Comment: However, this returns on Catalina `Warning: nginx must be run as non-root to start at user login!`.